# Trouble with british glyphs

Tags: harftex, luahbtex

If I use `\setmainfont` directive in my document, this is what I get instead of british glyphs!

[image]

What's the reason of this problem and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harfload, fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Bengali}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]

\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
    বাংলা \textbf{বাংলা}\\
    English
\end{document}
```

Comment: Noto Sans Bengali does not contain the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @Thérèse, you're right! Post it as an answer.

Comment: but your question is presumably wrong, as it implies that this works in Windows and not in some other operating system.

Comment: I can’t answer today — no internet connection except on my phone. But the question title should be edited: KDE has nothing to do with the problem (and the glyphs are Latin).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I didn't know that I was wrong until I installed Kalpurush.ttf on my system!

Comment: I mean you stated that "On windows 10, we don't have this problem! " but you must have had that problem on windows as well. How is Kalpurush.ttf  related? The question is about Noto Sans.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ok, edited.

Comment: Judging by the multi-linguistic setup, you may want to start using [`polyglossia`](https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia).

Comment: @RuixiZhang, I don't need polyglossia in luatex + harftex for multilingual document. I used Arabic, Bangla and English in the same document with fontspec and arabluatex. In this case, problem was in font as mentioned by Thérèse. If I use Kalpurush or Sutonny, I've no problem with English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Noto Sans Bengali does not contain glyphs for the Latin alphabet.

You may have thought it did if working in a word processor on Windows, because such programs may silently substitute other fonts when glyphs are missing.  `harftex` gives you more control and, in consequence, requires you to say exactly what you want.

Here’s one way to do that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harfload,fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Bengali}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
\newfontfamily\british{Noto Sans}[Script=Latin]
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
বাংলা \textbf{বাংলা}\\
\british English
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

## UPDATE

As of November 2019, you can install `luahbtex` and replace the lines

```
\usepackage{harfload,fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Bengali}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
```

with these:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Bengali}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Bengali]
```

See [Ulrike Fischer’s explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493185) for details.

Comment: +1: 10k very close :)

Comment: Could you update the answer so that it used luahbtex instead of harftex? See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493185/2388